# Difference between higher-kinded type members declaration

Tags: scala, syntax, types, shapeless, higher-kinded-types

Looking at the sources for shapeless library, i've paid attention to different higher-kinded type member declaration and wondering if it has some concrete difference in usage. For example generic trait [here](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/generic1.scala#L29):

```
trait Generic1[F[_], FR[_[_]]] {
  type R[t]
  // ...
}

trait IsHCons1[L[_], FH[_[_]], FT[_[_]]] {
  type H[_]
  // ...
}
```

One type member is declared with a common syntax for type constructors (i.e `H[_]`) and `Generic1` trait has `R[t]`. Though auxiliary type aliases are defined in a similar fashion:

```
object Generic1 {
  type Aux[F[_], FR[_[_]], R0[_]] = Generic1[F, FR] { type R[t] = R0[t] }
  // ...
}

object IsHCons1 {
  type Aux[L[_], FH[_[_]], FT[_[_]], H0[_], T0[_] <: HList] = IsHCons1[L, FH, FT] { type H[t] = H0[t] ; type T[t] = T0[t] }
  // ...
}
```

So i wonder if `R[t]` and `H[_]` has any difference or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference, as `t` is just unbound. You can easily verify this in the REPL:

```
scala> type T1 = { type R[t] }
defined type alias T1

scala> type T2 = { type R[_] }
defined type alias T2

scala> implicitly[T1 =:= T2]
res0: =:=[T1,T2] = <function1>
```

The fact that the last line compiles proves that the compiler sees `T1` and `T2` as the same type.

Comment: Yup ... there's no compelling reason to change it, but next time I'm touching things in that area I'll most likely alter the abstract definition of `R` to `type R[_]`. PRs also welcome :-)